# How To get factor of two numbers in python?

Tags: python

```
def gcd(x, y):
    (x, y) = (y, x) if x > y else (x, y)
    for factor in range(x, 0, -1):
        if x % factor == 0 and y % factor == 0:
            return factor
```

What is the use of the code:

```
(x, y) = (y, x) if x > y else (x, y)
```

Isn’t it enough to get the factor through the rest of the code? I have tried to get rid of the first line and the code went wrong, but I still can’t understand it.

Comment: You need to understand the algorithm of GCD. In essence the line is to make sure x is less than y.

Answer (score 0):

This insurances that the resulting x is always smaller then y.